# parsing structures through va_arg

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Say, among other elements I want to parse a C structure, from file1.c :

```
typedef struct mynode{
   int* x;
   int length;
}node;

int callerFunction(int myLength){
  //memory space  
  node* n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

  //dummy values for explanation purpose only
  double d = 3.14;
  int max  = 100;



//populate struct
  n->length = myLength;
  for(int i =0; i < n->length; i++)
     n->x[i]= i;

  //calling foo passing an structure  
   int result = foo(3,d,max,n);
}
```

and I want to pass this structure to another function via va_arg, in file2.c

```
int foo(int n,...){

int foo_max;
double foo_d;
node* foo_n;
va_list ap;

va_start(ap,n);  
 d = va_arg(ap,double);
 foo_d = va_arg(ap,int);
 foo_n = va_arg(ap,node*);
va_end(ap);
....
}
```

I thought I was doing the right thing, however if I include the structure, the data collected by foo is totally wrong (not the right data). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you talking about passing _structs_ or _pointers to structs_?

Comment: This looks like more of a C question than C++.

Comment: Are you initializing `n.x` in your real code (assuming this is just part of it)? If not, your _populate struct_ part is writing to some random location. This might be the reason for this total wrongness.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I include the structure"? If you have code that doesn't work, post *that*. And what do you mean by "totally wrong"? Is d not 3.14? (And why isn't it declared?) Is foo_d not 100? And why do the variable names in foo not match what is being passed to it? Post the *actual code that fails*, and what results it gets and how they differ from what you expect.

Comment: As I commented on @programmer's (correct) response, do not cast the return value of malloc in C.  It is completely unnecessary and, under older version of the standard, may hide the fact that you forgot to include `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `callerFunction`
seems like you have not allocated memory for `n->x` but using it.

```
 //populate struct
 n->length = myLength;

 n->x = malloc(n->lenght * sizeof(int));     //////////add this line

 for(int i =0; i < n->length; i++)
     n->x[i]= i;
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc in C.  It is completely unnecessary and, under older version of the standard, may hide the fact that you forgot to include `stdlib.h`.  Otherwise this is correct. +1